# symfony 2.6.x jquery installation best way

Tags: jquery, symfony

I red different ways to install jquery in a symfony project but what is the best ?

**Via Composer**

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.9.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jquery/jquery":                        "1.9.*"
    }
}
```

**Via composer with a package**

https://packagist.org/packages/components/jquery

**Via composer other explanation**

http://rigaudie.fr/articles/symfony/mise-a-jour-jquery-dans-symfony-via-composer

```
{
 "require": {
       ...
        "jquery/jquery": "2.*"
    },
    "repositories": [  
        {  
            "type": "package",  
            "package": {  
                "name": "jquery/jquery",  
                "version": "2.1.1",  
                "source":{  
                    "url":"https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git",  
                    "type":"git",  
                    "reference":"2.1.1"  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd":  "cd vendor/jquery/jquery && npm install -g grunt-cli",
        "post-install-cmd": [
            ...
            "cd vendor/jquery/jquery && npm install",  
            "cd vendor/jquery/jquery && grunt dist:../../../app/Resources/public/js/"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            ...
            "cd vendor/jquery/jquery && grunt dist:../../../app/Resources/public/js/"
        ]
    },
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, and if you will have more javascript libraries, Bower is a very good solution.

composer is good for PHP projects, Bower is good for javascripts projects (and jquery is ...)

See http://bower.io/ for more details

You will have to :

- install npm
- install bower : npm install -g bower
- create a bower.json file at the root of your project

  {
      "name": "myproject",
      "dependencies": {
          "jquery": "1.10.*",
          "jquery-ui": "1.10.*"
    }
- create a .bower.rc file

  {
    "directory": "web/vendor",
    "json": "bower.json"
  }
- install : bower install